# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve ai.api:sdk:2.0.7

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I want to integrate `dialogflow` in my *app* but, when I sync dependencies it still showing me this error:

> **ERROR:** Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve ai.api:sdk:2.0.7.
>
> Disable offline mode and sync project
>   Show Details
>
> Affected Modules: app
>
> **ERROR:** Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve ai.api:libai:1.6.12.
>
> Disable offline mode and sync project
>   Show Details
>
> Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 0):

U need to disable offline mode to be able to sync and import new dependencies

click on `File`(top right) -> click on `Settings`...  -> click on `Gradle` -> Under `Global Gradle settings` -> uncheck `offline work`